# Why image becomes darkers and low resolution when export to PDF?

Tags: pdf, svg, visio

I'm having a problem exporting my image to PDF in Visio. 
I have a scalable vector graphics image (svg).

 Here is how the image looks opened in Chrome or Forxit Reader which looks good.

[image]

Now I open the svg image in Visio and then export it to PDF with these settings.

[image]

[image]

Finally if I open the resulting PDF image in Chrome or in Foxit Reader and now you can see that the image looks different from my svg image and the yellow background part becomes darker.

[image]

Also if I zoom in the lines look broken and look like it has low resolution.

[image]

I tried it in my other laptop and the problem doesn't have one my laptop. I reinstalled Visio to be the same version as the one in my laptop but it doesn't solve the problem.

 Does anyone know what problem is this and how can I fix this?

I'm going to attach my svg image and PDF here in case you need to examine them.

1. https://svgshare.com/i/ifV.svg
2. https://pdfhost.io/v/Oq83.Aiqo_myplot

Answer (score 1):

All graphics in your PDF were rendered as bitmap images.
Only the numbers are still svg text.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there any reason how did that happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know Visio, so I'm afraid, I can't help you with its export settings. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try utility [SVG publish add-in](https://unmanagedvisio.com/products/svg-publish/)

Comment: If you don't mind could you show how can I use it for this specific example? I  downloaded and installed it but sitll not quite sure how to use it. I read the reference but seems like it's for exporting to html not pdf.

Comment: I agree with the statement "All graphics in your PDF were rendered as bitmap images. Only the numbers are still svg text". When using this tool, the conversion is done with minimal distortion. The resulting HTML (SVG) should then be exported to PDF.

Comment: Could you show how to do it with the tool? I have been trying for some time but couldn't find where to export it to PDF?

Comment: Seem like you suggesting convert it to html and then from html to PDF. I did that but the PDF is low quality.

Comment: Did you export from Visio to HTML with built-in Visio tools ? 
**IMHO** this tool make conversion not best.

Comment: No, I use Visio to html using the tool you said and then convert from html to PDF using pdf printer.